# behaviors of the (<|>) operator of haskell parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to use RPN interpreter to practice the use of Parsec, and here is my code:

```
module RPN where
import Control.Applicative hiding((<|>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec 
data RPNVal = Add|Sub|Mul|Div|Num Double deriving(Show)
a <:> b  = (:) <$> a <*> b
a <++> b = (++) <$> a <*> b
opSymbol = oneOf "+-*/"
number   = many1 digit :: Parser String
plus     = char '+' *> number
minus    = char '-' <:> number
integer  = (number <|> minus <|> plus) :: Parser String
float    = integer <++> decimal <++> exponent
    where decimal  = option "" $ char '.' <:> number
          exponent = option "" $ oneOf "eE" <:> number
parseOp :: Parser RPNVal
parseOp = do
    op <- opSymbol
    case op of 
         '+' -> return Add 
         '-' -> return Sub 
         '*' -> return Mul 
         '/' -> return Div
parseNum :: Parser RPNVal
parseNum = liftA (read::String->Double) float >>= return.Num
parseRPNVal :: Parser RPNVal 
-- parseRPNVal = parseOp <|> parseNum
-- parseRPNVal = parseNum <|> parseOp
parseRPNVal = try parseNum <|> parseOp
parseExpr :: Parser [RPNVal]
parseExpr = parseRPNVal `sepBy1` spaces
readExpr :: String->[RPNVal]
readExpr input = case parse parseExpr "RPN" input of
                      Left errMsg -> error $ show errMsg
                      Right val   -> val
```

in the definition of `parseRPNVal`, I found that if I use `parseRPNVal = parseOp <|> parseNum`, then the parser worked well, however, if I use `parseRPNVal = parseNum <|> parseOp`, then the function could only parse numbers while operators would cause error.

In [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html), it says:

> This operator behaves like this: it will first try the parser on the
>   left. If it consumed no input[35], it will try the parser on the right

so could anyone please explain the behavior of `parseOp` and `parseNum` to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just as Real World Haskell says.

`parseNum` first parses an [`integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Token.html#v:integer), but `integer`-s can be prefixed with `+` or `-`.

Therefore, when parsing `parseNum <|> parseOp`, if the next character is `+` or `-`, and what we actually have is an operator, `parseNum` reads in that character and fails only afterwards.

With `parseOp <|> parseNum`, no backtracking is needed, of course, since `parseOp` needs just one character lookahead.